# Typescript does not include svg in build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

i have a problem, that my build via `tsc --project tsconfig.dist.json` (see file below) does not include the assets (.svg) that are importet and used in the code in the build. So what do i have to do for typescript to include those in the build?

Maybe some background: it is a `create-react-app` project, using react scripts etc. A normal `npm start` works fine and also loads the assets where needed and used in the project. However the build does not include those files.

The `tsconfig.dist.json` only references the base project config and sets output options.

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "outDir": "./dist"
    }
}
```

Usage Example (the assets folder is within the src-folder btw):

```
import image from '../assets/disconnected.svg';
import { ReactComponent } from '../assets/disconnected.svg';
```

**Edit because maybe it was not clear:**
It does not affect webpack. It is about a standalone usage of `tsc` directly, that does not complain about errors but does not include those assets in the emitted code, making the emitted code by `tsc` fail.

Comment: are you importing the svgs as jsx elements or are you using files path to load your svgs?

Comment: sorry, i forgot that there is a difference and to include an example - in added it to the question. So i am importing the elements i would say. I am not quite sure how the default loaders process the imports of svg but at least the `ReactComponent` import should import it _as a component_

Comment: Maybe another important note, that the compiler does not produce an error. It simply does not include the svgs in the produced code.

Comment: This is something to do with webpack and react not typescript.

Comment: No it only occurs when using tsc without webpack, so the questions is merely about standalone `tsc`

Answer (score 1):

This is not about typescript. You have imported it wrong.

```
import image from '../assets/disconnected.svg'; // this one is correct
import { ReactComponent } from '../assets/disconnected.svg'; // this one is wrong
```

Comment: Hi i am using both. The are both correct and display the images fine. The problem is only when using `tsc` without webpack in emit mode.

Comment: When using the TypeScript Compiler (TSC) directly without a bundler like webpack, it doesn't handle asset files like SVGs automatically. TSC is primarily focused on compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript and doesn't have built-in support for bundling or including non-code assets.

Comment: it's recommended to use the built-in webpack configuration for your project. Webpack has extensive support for handling assets, including SVG files, and can automatically include them in the build output. By using the npm run build command provided by CRA, the bundling and asset inclusion will be handled correctly.

Comment: Your point might be true, but that is not the question. I do not need a bundled version in this particular case, because it is more a library where i need only the compiled code not a minified webpack version. There are a lot of valid usecases, i.e. non web-based typescript projects, component libraries where you need that. So i would say, there must be some ways to handle that with `tsc` only

Comment: When you say it does not handle them automatically, do you know how to add that? After all `tsc` does not warn and thus emits unusable code, which i would say is errorneous behavior. I tried steps having a module declaration for *.svg etc. Btw. a workaround is just to copy those assets file along the emitted code manually - but this is not really nice

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about TSC.